# Concat df from different excel sheets in different excel files

Tags: python, excel, pandas, append, concatenation

I want to concat certain excel sheets from multiple excel files into one dataframe. At the moment, I manually copy the sheets (f.ex. named "11062021_sheet", "180622_sheet"), paste them into a new excel file, name each sheet to "Round X" and execute the following code:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(INPUT, sheet_name = 'Round 2')
df2 = pd.read_excel(INPUT, sheet_name = 'Round 3') 
df3 = pd.read_excel(INPUT, sheet_name = 'Round 4')
df4 = pd.read_excel(INPUT, sheet_name = 'Round 5')
df5 = pd.read_excel(INPUT, sheet_name = 'Round 6')
df6 = pd.read_excel(INPUT, sheet_name = 'Round 7')
df7 = pd.read_excel(INPUT, sheet_name = 'Round 8')
df8 = pd.read_excel(INPUT, sheet_name = 'Round 9')
df9 = pd.read_excel(INPUT, sheet_name = 'Round 10')
df10 = pd.read_excel(INPUT, sheet_name = 'Round 11')
df11 = pd.read_excel(INPUT, sheet_name = 'Round 12')

df = df0.append([df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8,df9,df10,df11], sort=False)
```

Does anybody know a quicker/leaner alternative? (Such as take all sheets that have the names "11062021_sheet", "180622_sheet" from all the files that in this folder and concat them into one list)

Answer (score 0):

Use `sheet_name = None` for get all sheetnames and then filter them in dictionary comprehension:

```
sheetnames = ['Round 2','Round 3',...'Round 12']

dfs = pd.read_excel(INPUT, sheet_name = None)

df = pd.concat({k: v for k, v in dfs.items() if k in sheetnames}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

EDIT: For function use:

```
def join_sheetnames(INPUT, sheetnames):

    dfs = pd.read_excel(INPUT, sheet_name = None)
    return (pd.concat({k: v for k, v in dfs.items() if k in sheetnames})
              .reset_index(drop=True))

L = ['Round 2','Round 3',...'Round 12']
df = join_sheetnames('file.xlsx', L)
```

EDIT: If there are different excel files with filenames:

```
L1 = [('file.xlsx','Round 2'),('file1.xlsx','Round 3'),('file2.xlsx','Round 4')]
df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(i, sheet_name = s) for i, s in L1])
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I put that into a function?

Comment: @questionoverflow - what is input in function?

Comment: Shouldn't be the sheets input and the df output?